# Why can't the data collection of the List be mapped to the entity object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<NumberEntity>, List<NumberDto>>();
var dto = new ResultDto<NumberDto>
{
    recordsTotal = query_count.Value,
    data = Mapper.Map<List<NumberEntity>, List<NumberDto>>(list)
};
return dto;
```

At this time, the list has already got the data，

Comment: I assumed that `Mapper.CreateMap` is from [tag:automapper] and so added the appropriate tag.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  As it is it's not clear how to reproduce your problem, or even exactly what the problem is.  Is there an exception?  A compilation error?  Something else?  See [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem... Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some... **Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.***  In this case there's not enough code for us to understand and reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html